# Height of the table to be constant

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to make a table let's say `400px height`, and I want this value to never change when I modify the height of table rows with `Javascript? Is there any property that allows height of rows never to be bigger than a certain value?

Comment: Refer to the following: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules.

Comment: When you specify the height to be fixed using css, the height of the table will not change. What exactly are you looking for? As @VisioN said you can use !important rule to force the height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. From your question I can guess that your table should not exceed more than 400px height even your total rows contains height more than 400px.

As per my understanding I would suggest you to put your table into div (having height of 400px and and overflow auto) as mentioned in below example :

```
<div style="max-height:400px;overflow:auto">
    <table>
        <tr style="height:500px">
            <td>
                Spider Code
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[**Note:** You can remove height from **tr**. I have put it just to indicate overflow.]

As per the above solution, if height exceeds 400px then scrollbar will be displayed.

And if you want your row height never exceed more than some pixels then set the max-height to row as mentioned below.

```
tr
{
 max-height:20px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: that is just an example I guess

Comment: Yes that's right. I have just given an example. thanks @hajirazin for mentioning :)

Answer (score 1):

What ever you set in tr's height in javascript it is meaning less if it exist the max-height. so give max-height property to your tr which will restrict you tr to grow more than max-height.

Answer (score 0):

use css `max-height` property for the table

```
tr{
max-height: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
table{
max-height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The poster was looking for Table Rows, not table height.

Comment: @MathewMacLean check it now